# CodeIgniter pagination Previous and active Links not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-url

I have a code where clicking on pagination links functions fine , but if i click on a link that particular link is not showing as active link .
my code is as follows

```
function viewcategory($name) {
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('categorypostmod');

    $page = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->library('table');

    $this->load->model("site_model");
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/b3/index.php/CategoryPost/viewcategory/" . $name . "/page/";
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;

    log_message('info', 'count is ' . $this->categorypostmod->getCategorycount($name));

    $config['total_rows'] = $this->categorypostmod->getCategorycount($name);
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';

    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['prev_link'] = ' Previous';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $data['query'] = $this->categorypostmod->getCategorypost($name, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(5));
    $records = $this->db->get('post', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(5));
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->view('script');
    $this->load->view('head');
    $this->load->view('cat_content_list', $data);

    $this->load->view('aside');
    $this->load->view('bottom');
}
```

Controller name is categorypost ,Please help me as the same code is working on other controller , i think i am missing the working of how links are created , looks like to me that CI is unable to get the link that is clicked is an active one , Please Help me onto this .

Comment: first error: you are loading `$this->load->helper("url");` twice. Try placing all your `load()` functions on the very top.

Comment: remove the trailing forward slash `/` at the end of your `base_url`

Comment: why do you have the `page` parameter in your URL `$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/b3/index.php/CategoryPost/viewcategory/" . $name . "/page/" `?

Comment: @codeGodie  Inside viewcategory i m passing parameter as category for eg. html and i wnat to get all records on basis of that , so i have given $name the parameter that i used in function , if i dont give that it will not able to get the param and search , am i with u on to this ? this is what you are asking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following code, let me know what results you get:

```
function viewcategory($name) {
    $this->load->database();

    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->helper('form');

    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $this->load->model('categorypostmod');
    $this->load->model("site_model");

    $page = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $categCount = $this->categorypostmod->getCategorycount($name);

    $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/b3/index.php/CategoryPost/viewcategory/" . $name . "/page/";
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;

    log_message('info', 'count is ' . $categCount);

    $config['total_rows'] = $categCount;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';

    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['prev_link'] = ' Previous';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $data['query'] = $this->categorypostmod->getCategorypost($name, $config['per_page'], $page);

    $records = $this->db->get('post', $config['per_page'], $page);

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);


    $this->load->view('script');
    $this->load->view('head');
    $this->load->view('cat_content_list', $data);

    $this->load->view('aside');
    $this->load->view('bottom');
}
```

Comment: also, where do you use the `$records` variable?

Comment: i have removed it actually now , i am sharing link where you can see how its working https://youtu.be/G6p7jm08uMk   and Sharing the model as well .

Comment: Please look at github url for model and controller  https://github.com/Sanjay007/Blog ,please let me know if  it helps .

Comment: ok gotcha. So it seems the `.active` class is not being added to your clicked `li` , if you check the elements with Web Developer tools, do you see the active class added?

Comment: nope active class is no there ..but adding $config['uri_segment'] = 5; worked , but i m nt getting how it solved? whereas in previous one i havnt added it but still it worked..

Comment: i have a model and i am calling it after page loads and execuing some function , why its getting executed 2-3 times ?   <code> $this->load->model('Aside_mod');
 if($this->Aside_mod->check_cat_exists($name)){

//print_r($this->Aside_mod->get_cat_count($name));
$this->Aside_mod->update_cat_count($name,$this->Aside_mod->get_cat_count($name)+1);
 }
 else{
 $this->Aside_mod->add_cat_views($name);
 
 }</code>

Answer (score 3):

You missed the configuration of uri_segment. Add this config

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 5;//for you its 5
```

Comment: Thanks Shaiful , it worked :) , but can you tell me what is its use and why it was not taking ???

Comment: CI pagination try to detect what is your current page number and which segment will be the page number.`uri_segment` tells which segment is your page numbering contains.If you don`t tell CI try to detect automatically which is actually segment 3.In you case segment 3 does not contains the page number so CI cannot detect the page number.Hope you understand what I mean

Comment: Thanks for the info ,  i was not aware  of it .Thanks Once Again

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 5 /*aca test values ​​( 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7)*/

$data['query'] = $this->categorypostmod->getCategorypost($name, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(5/*aca test values ​​( 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7)*/) )
```

Try uri with each of the values ​​`(1,2,3,4)`.

You can work with the number 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6.